# odoo create a new new view Uncaught Promise > No view found for act_window action 139

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-16

I'm a newbie to Odoo development, trying to create a custom view from scratch. The documentation is quit hard at least couldn’t figure out how to create a new custom view, then, I was following *[Odoo Experience 2018 - How to Create a New View](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SIoljYJhTqk)* whenever trying to open module getting error **Uncaught Promise > No view found for act_window action 139**.
[image]

I have no idea why *act_window action* id not found! Kindly help me to fix this issue or suggest me an example for creating custom view in Odoo 16. Thanks.

Here below the source code for custom hello_world_view

***menifest**.py*

```
{
    'name': "Hello World",

    'summary': "Say Hello",
    'description': """
        Say Hellow to the world
    """,

    'version': '0.1',
    'depends': ['web', 'contacts', 'base_geolocalize'],
    'data': [
        "views/data.xml"
    ],
    'assets': {
        'web.assets_backend': [
            'hello_world_view/static/src/js/hello_world_view.js',
            'hello_world_view/static/src/scss/hello_world_view.scss',
        ],
    },
    'installable': True,
    'auto_install': True
}
```

*ir_action.py*

```
from odoo import models, fields


class ActionWindow(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'ir.actions.act_window.view'

    view_mode = fields.Selection(
        selection_add=[('hello_world', "Hello World")],
        ondelete={'hello_world': 'cascade'}
    )
```

*ir_ui_view.py*

```
class View(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'ir.ui.view'

    type = fields.Selection(
        selection_add=[('hello_world', "Hello World")]
    )
```

*hello_world_view.js*

```
odoo.define('hello_world_view.HelloWorldView', function (require) {
    "use strict";

    var AbstractAction = require('web.AbstractAction');
    var core = require('web.core');

    var QWeb = core.qweb;

    var HelloWorldView = AbstractAction.extend({
        template: 'HelloWorldTemplate',
        init: function (parent, options) {
            this._super.apply(this, arguments);
            this.data = options.data;
        },
    });

    core.action_registry.add('hello_world_view', HelloWorldView);

    return HelloWorldView;
});
```

*data.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<odoo>

    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="hello_world_view_1">
        <field name="model">res.partner</field>
        <field name="mode">primary</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <hello_world> </hello_world>
        </field>
    </record>

    <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="first_hello_world_view">
        <field name="name">Hello World</field>
        <field name="res_model">res.partner</field>
        <field name="view_mode">hello_world</field>
        <field name="view_id" ref="hello_world_view_1"/>
    </record>

    <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="second_hello_world_view">
        <field name="name">Hello World</field>
        <field name="res_model">res.partner</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
<!--        <field name="view_id" ref="hello_world_view_2"/>-->
    </record>

    <menuitem id="main_hello_world_menu" name="Hello World App"/>

    <menuitem id="hello_world_submenu" name="Hello World Menu"
              parent="main_hello_world_menu"/>

    <menuitem id="open_view" name="Open Hello World View" parent="hello_world_submenu"
              action="first_hello_world_view"/>

</odoo>
```

Comment: What Odoo version you are using?

Comment: @WaleedMohsen I'm using Odoo 16 version for this

Comment: The  "Odoo Experience 2018 - How to Create a New View" is for Odoo 12 and it's an advance tutorail for how to add a view types to Odoo views. You can follow the Odoo tutorial or search for courses in YouTube. for example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Az8G4Y5r3Xg

Comment: Yes it's an advance topic, I need to create custom view that's why I was trying this. I hope it's possible to do in Odoo 16 too.

Comment: Yes you can do it in Odoo 16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Odoo will fail to get `hello_world` view from the registry because you registered `hello_world_view` in the action registry

To fix the issue you need to register it in the views registry.

The Odoo framework changed a lot and you may encounter other issues

Try the following minimal view:

```
/** @odoo-module **/
import AbstractView from "web.AbstractView";
import view_registry from 'web.view_registry';


export const HelloWorldView =  AbstractView.extend({
    viewType: 'hello_world',
});

view_registry.add('hello_world', HelloWorldView)

return HelloWorldView;
```

Comment: Thanks it's working, would please give me a example Creating a view from scratch. It's little hard to follow odoo doc

Comment: **From Odoo tutorials:** *Let us see how one can [create a new view, completely from scratch.](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/16.0/developer/tutorials/master_odoo_web_framework/04_creating_view_from_scratch.html#chapter-4-creating-a-view-from-scratch) In a way, it is not very difficult to do, but there are no really good resources on how to do it.*